# Normalized cross correlation coefficients

Tags: c#, normalization, cross-correlation

I have implemented the cross-correlation between two arrays in my C# code. I strictly applied this formula `corr(a, b) = ifft(fft(a_and_zeros) * conj(fft(b_and_zeros)))`, using the help of the Accord Framework, and it works fine for the most part. I get an array of correlation coefficients that I can further use.

However, I have not been able to find how to calculate the normalized correlation coefficients. Anyone can shed some light on it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps divide all the coefficients by the max  coefficient value?

Comment: I should have said divide by the maximum magnitude (absolute value) of the coefficients.

Comment: Maybe https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for such question.

Comment: @Aybe Yes, maybe this would help https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36171/how-do-i-know-quantitatively-if-the-correlation-of-two-time-series-is-significan/40943#40943